# Boostrap4 change background of active anchor tag

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7

I have trying to build a dynamic list of anchor tags using *ngFor on angular and i am not able to change the background color for the selected active anchor tag,
My maing html is as follow:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <app-zona-item
  *ngFor="let zonaEl of zonas"
  [zona]="zonaEl"></app-zona-item>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
   <h5>Lugares de estacionamento</h5>
 </div>
</div>
```

My app-zone-item html is as follow:

```
<a
style="cursor: pointer;"
routerLinkActive="active"
class="list-group-item clearfix">
 <div class="pull-left">
  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{zona.designacaoZona}}</h4>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">{{zona._id}}</p>
 </div>
</a>
```

It renders the following list:

[image]

How to change the background of the selected active tag. In Boostrap 3 this code is working, but in bootstrap 4 not anymore. What I need to change, or is there another way to achieve the same result. When clicking on one item I want to show the active anchor tag and use the id to displays details on the other div

Comment: Please create demo to reproduce an issue

Comment: I may look stupid, but how i can create a demo here on stack, I saw it one, but i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

well, you just need little css to change background color of active anchor tag, just add following css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <style>
   a:active {
    background: orange !important;
   }
  </style>
  <a href="#">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>

 </body>
</html>
```